# Why the date from DB will never same format as new Date()?

Tags: java

Basically my objective is to use a date as a salt key to encrypt my password. I was using SHA-512 for doing this. When I encrypt my password, I capture today's date, say varDate, which is a `java.util.Date` type, and then do the encryption. If I output it by doing this `varDate.toString()`, I will see `Thu Jul 18 17:37:27 SGT 2013`. Then after this `varDate` will be store into DB.

When come to decryption, I will supply my password and query the `varDate` from DB, which is also in `java.util.Date` type, encrypt it and do the comparison. Interestingly this will always failed because the encrypted value will never match. I found out that when I output the `varDate`, which is from DB, is having this format `2013-07-18 17:37:27.0`.

I was so surprise and so curious and struggling why this happen? I wonder whether this is the root cause which causing the encryption failed?

## UPDATE ON 23-07-2013

This is to illustrate how the code work on my hashing algorithm. I have a function that accept password as a String, and a salt key as a String, then do the hashing on the password like this:

```
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
   md.reset();
   md.update(saltKey.getBytes());
   md.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

My experiment shows that by passing in Date object, I couldn't get a consistent result. But if I reformatting it to a string, then only I'll get a consistent result. This seem to me that date object isn't a good salt key candidate.

Comment: Side note: you're **hashing** your password, not encrypting.

Comment: sorry my bad, I'm hashing.

Comment: Can you please show how do you use Date as salt? And how do you recover the salt?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `Date.toString()`. Its output depends on the actual concrete type of the date, which could be `java.util.Date` (your first case, presumably), `java.sql.Timestamp` (your second case, presumably) or `java.sql.Date`. It also depends on the current timezone.

My advice would be to forget about using dates for the salt completely. Use a SecureRandom to generate a random salt, and store this salt in the database.

If you really persist in using a Date, then transform it to a String using a reliable mechanism, like a `SimpleDateFormat` with a fixed pattern and the UTC timezone, for example.

Comment: If I use SecureRandom to generate a random salt, may I know can I store the salt key in KeyStore or JKS file?

Comment: Which salt key are you talking about? You generate a random salt for each user, and store the salt in the user row, next to the login and hashed password. No key is involved.

Comment: I was about to change my design, where I use constant salt key (generate from SecureRandom) store into a file, which is a keystore file. The salt key is use together with login password for hashing.

Answer (score 1):

Always format your dates, converting them from date/time type to strings using an explicit format. That way you'll always get what you want, and you won't be relying on the system default formats (which can be changed and reconfigured by the user).